# Group inside group linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I have a datatable like this:

I want to group this table For FIELD A and FIELD B,
and the third field of my group should be lists of FIELD C, but it must be grouped by ID field.

At the end, the result should be like this:

```
First Field | Second Field |  Third Field
------------+--------------+----------------
     5      |     XXXX     |(8) (2,6,3) (9)  
     5      |     KKKK     |(8,3)
```

The third field must be a list of lists.

How can i do this with LINQ?

I tried this so far:

```
        var trytogroup = (from p in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                                group p by new
                                {
                                    ID = p["Id"].ToLong(),
                                    FieldA = p["FieldA"].ToLong(),
                                    FieldB = p["FieldB"].ToString()
                                } into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    FirstField = g.Key.FieldA,
                                    SecondField = g.Key.FieldB,
                                    ThirdField = datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p["FieldA"].ToLong() == g.Key.FieldA && p["FieldB"].ToString() == g.Key.FieldB).Select(p => p["FieldC"].ToLong()).GroupBy(x => x["Id"].ToLong()).Distinct().ToList()
                                });
```

[image]

Comment: What error do you have with your LINQ query?

Comment: I didnt get any errors, but i cant groupe the third field. Field A an Field B is ok, bu the third field must be a list of lists, i cant do that

Comment: can you please show how you tried to group third field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with your query:

- You don't need to group by three fields on first place. Grouping by ID should be done within group which you have by FieldA and FieldB
- When getting ThirdField you don't need to query datatable again - you already have all required data. You just need to add grouping by ID

Correct query:

```
 from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
 group r by new {
   FieldA = r.Field<long>("FieldA"),
   FieldB = r.Field<string>("FieldB")
 } into g
 select new
 {
     First = g.Key.FieldA,
     Second = g.Key.FieldB,
     Third = g.GroupBy(r => r.Field<long>("ID"))
              .Select(idGroup => idGroup.Select(i => i.Field<long>("FieldC")).ToList())
 }
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, just curious also as a fresh mind to the whole `GroupBy` grouping

Comment: @ColinM what do you mean by ThenBy? It's applicable to ordered sequences

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: What I meant was syntax like `datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy().ThenBy()`, but on further inspection that wouldn't work as you have above since the second grouping is on items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefere lambdas, your query could look like:

```
dataSource
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.FieldA, item.FieldB })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        First = group.Key.FieldA,
        Second = group.Key.FieldB,
        Third = group.GroupBy(q => q.Id).Select(q => q.Select(e => e.FieldC).ToArray()).ToArray()
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just few small notes. `.GroupBy` uses [`Lookup`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,60e7f83f7c37000f) to get the `Grouping`s, so some overhead can be avoided by replacing `.GroupBy(` with `.ToLookup(` when deffered execution is not needed.

The elements in each `Grouping` are [stored in array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7bb231e0604c79e3), so I don't see much use in converting them `.ToList` (but you can save a bit of space if you convert them `.ToArray`).

`DataTable.AsEnumerable` uses [`.Rows.Cast<TRow>()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/EnumerableRowCollection.cs,068ee8343125ebde), but also seems to do some extra stuff when there is any `DataView` sorting or filtering that are usually not needed.

```
var groups = datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .ToLookup(r => Tuple.Create(
        r["FieldA"] as long?,
        r["FieldB"]?.ToString()
    ))
    .Select(g => Tuple.Create(
        g.Key.Item1, 
        g.Key.Item2,
        g.ToLookup(r => r["ID"] as long?, r => r["FieldC"] as long?)
    )).ToList();
```

As usual, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) but I thought the information might be useful.